# Backend architecture for iOS map application

Tags: ios, database, architecture, azure-mobile-services, nosql

I have researched quite abit on this topic, but I can't seem to understand/find enough information on my issue.

I'm new in a small software company, where I just got a project in which I need to write the technical requirement specification.

We are developing an iOS map app where a user can create a map based on a city in which the user can add points of interest, and add pictures to these along with descriptions etc. The point being, that the user can share travel experiences from a given city with other users.

My problem is then, that I need to describe the overall system architecture and decide on how the backend solution should be composed. I have no prior experience with system architecture.

I have looked at what Microsoft Azure can at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/ and specifically the Standard S1 plan option. But I don't know if this solution will be enough if the user base of the app will be, let's say, 20.000 users? And is a NoSQL database included in this or can it be?

I apologise if there exists similar questions to this that I have overlooked!

Hope anyone can chip in with some overall advice

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

An App Service provides just the web hosting capability.  That's a fairly broad capability and includes lots of scaling features.  It can scale (in that if the backend you write is stateless, you can run multiple copies) and has all the DevOps requirements you will need.

To that basic backend, you are going to want to add other features.  DocumentDb, or Azure Table Storage all provide NoSQL capabilities, with differences being in latency, query ability, and resiliency.  You could also opt for a SQL database, blob storage or place your own database or a third party database in the architecture.

System Architecture is too broad and vague without real requirements.  Asking if a specific solution is suitable for such a broad and vague solution is not really appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
     mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:
       CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 300)];
       mapView.delegate = self;
       mapView.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.32, -122.03);
       mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
       CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
       location.latitude = (double) 37.332768;
       location.longitude = (double) -122.030039;
       // Add the annotation to our map view
       MapAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc]
       initWithTitle:@"Apple Head quaters" andCoordinate:location];
       [mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
       CLLocationCoordinate2D location2;
       location2.latitude = (double) 37.35239;
       location2.longitude = (double) -122.025919;
       MapAnnotation *newAnnotation2 = [[MapAnnotation alloc] 
       initWithTitle:@"Test annotation" andCoordinate:location2];
       [mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation2];
       [self.view addSubview:mapView];

}


// When a map annotation point is added, zoom to it (1500 range)
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
   MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
   id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
   MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance
   ([mp coordinate], 1500, 1500);
   [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
   [mv selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];
}
```

you can edit according to you
Note:you need to implement popUp(custom).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I'm not quite sure that this will answer my, somewhat broad and perhaps vague, question.I was more looking for advice on whether the linked solution would be enough and if it was possible to use a NoSQL database with it. Or if another solution would be better.